# Set keyboard layout for a specific website opened in Google Chrome on MacOS?

Tags: macos, google-chrome

Is it possible to set a certain keyboard layout (language) when a specific website is opened in Google Chrome on MacOS?

So far I could only find apps that set a layout based on an opened app but not website.

Comment: This [post](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/312691/is-there-a-macos-utility-that-lets-me-assign-a-keyboard-shortcut-for-switching-t) might help.

Comment: @harrymc - that might work if you're "in charge" of the switch, but the 'auto-detector' looks tough - beyond my limited Applescript. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23729704/change-osx-keyboard-layoutinput-source-programmatically-via-terminal-or-appl and https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/376922/switch-to-a-specific-input-source-in-os-x-in-catalina-with-applescript [which are *way* above my paygrade ;)